# SQL query to find How many employees joined in one week

Tags: sql, oracle11g

i tried following

select count(emp_id),emp_jn_dt 
from employee
where emp_jn_dt between '01-nov-2014' AND '07-nov-2014'
group by emp_jn_dt)
order by emp_jn_dt ;

But then my sir asked what if i enter data dynamically?

i have no clue on this. Plz help me out
thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't matter that data enter dynamically but emp_in_dt must be `System.DateTime.Now` so that if u want to select last week records then u should pass 2 dates 1st date should be `System.DateTime.Now` and 2)`DateTime d=System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7)` i.e d

Try this and if find any difficulty or need more clarification please let me know

Comment: yes please clarify ,i almost got what you've said  but more clarification will help. sample query would help me much more. thank you

Comment: Create one stored procedure that will accept two dates Example:CREATE PROCEDURE SP_Details
(
  @Date1   DATE
 ,@Date2   DATE
)
AS
BEGIN
 SELECT COUNT(emp_id),emp_jn_dt FROM employee WHERE emp_jn_dt between (@Date1 AND @Date2) 
 GROUP BY emp_jn_dt ORDER BY emp_jn_dt  
END

Comment: Pass Date1 as d and Date2 as DateTime.Now. Waiting for your reply